# Query on multiple database

Tags: php, mysql

I add mysql_errno() at the connection. And the errors is 2nd database doesn't exist. So that why the query cannot be proceed. So what the correct code to make this 2 database connected?

```
//database connection  
 $serverhost = "localhost"; //put in your mysql server host #example : localhost
    $databasename1 = "database1"; //1st database name
        $databasename2 = "database2"; // 2nd database name 
    $loginname = "root"; //put in your mysql username
    $loginpswd = "*****"; //put in your mysql password

$conn1 = mysql_connect($serverhost,$loginname,$loginpswd);
```

mysql_select_db($databasename1,$conn1);
    echo mysql_errno($conn1) . ": " . mysql_error($conn1). "\n";

```
$conn2 = mysql_connect($serverhost, $loginname, $loginpswd);
mysql_select_db($databasename2, $conn2);
echo mysql_errno($conn2) . ": " . mysql_error($conn2). "\n";
```

Comment: add error checking to the query if you want to see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_` api is also deprecated and you should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`.  I recommend `PDO` since it supports multiple DBMS.

`mysql_query` accepts the resource or connection as the second argument.  You can't use two different connections in the same query but you don't need two different connections from the looks of it.  As @Dagon pointed out, mysql_query will use the latest opened connection so your first connection isn't even being used.

You should be able to just use one connection to the MySQL server and specify the databases in the query as you have it assuming your user has access to both databases.

The problem most likely lies in your query.  Try running it directly on the MySQL server and see if it succeeds or use [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) if you are certain you want to continue using the deprecated mysql api.

Comment: "If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. " so its going to use $conn2 in this case. but th issue is going to be with the actual query which he need to add basic error checking to

Comment: @Dagon, yes you're right.  My answer is just pointing out issues in the OP code but was just too long as a comment.

Comment: @Dagon can you just give some example to make it clear explanation. I have no idea to solve it. Thanks

Comment: @user3408496 Use my suggestions and also look into `mysql_error()`.  I put a link in my edited answer and che-azeh put an example in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Devon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583522/devon) answern above, it would also help to always check for mysql errors. So your query could be enhanced if you add the following lines after the query:

```
if(!$result) {

    echo mysql_error($conn1)
}
```

Comment: the error saids the second database doesnt exist. So I think the database connection code is prob. So what should I do?

Comment: Depending if the OP updates his code on my suggestions, $conn1 is unused in the current code.  So you should probably leave the resource null (remove $conn1).

Comment: @user3408496, update your question with the error message and any code changes you made.

Comment: @den you didn't include your error message and why are you still using two connections?

Comment: @Devon just because I want to form a table which retrieve the data between 2 database. thats why Im using 2 db

Comment: @den, did you read my answer?  You don't need two connections to use two databases.  Your connection is completely redundant and `$conn1` is never even used because `mysql_query` just uses the last opened connection if a connection isn't specified.

Comment: @Devon so we just make connection for 2nd database?

Comment: @den It doesn't matter which one you use.  The connections both use the same parameters, they are redundant. You're specifying the databases in the query so why do you need two connections?